# How to find the matrix of $T$ for the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, independence

Let $V$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space,and suppose $T: V:\rightarrow V$ has matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}$ relative to the basis $\alpha=\{v_1,v_2\}$ for $V$.

$\Bbb{a)}$ Find the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $\alpha'=\{v_1,v_2\}$ where $v'_1=3v_1+v_2,\ v'_2=5v_1+2v_2$

$\Bbb{b)}$ Show that $T(v_1+2v_2)$ is independent of the choice matrix of $T$.

For Qa, I think we can write $[T]^{a'}_{a'}=[I]^{a'}_{a}[T]^{a}_{a}[I]^{a}_{a'}=[[I]^{a}_{a'}]^{-1}[T]^{a}_{a}[I]^{a}_{a'}$. However, I have trouble finding $[I]^{a}_{a'}$. I guess it is $\begin{bmatrix}3&5\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$?

For Qb, I don't have idea how to start the problem. Which kind of matrix should I write?

Comment: I think that $\alpha'=\{v_1',v_2'\}$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To find the matrix representation of a linear transformation in a given ordered basis, apply the linear transformation to each basis vector and write the result as a linear combination of the basis vectors.  The coefficients give the columns of the matrix.

Since $v_1'= 3v_1+ v_2$, $Tv_1'= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}= 7v_1+ 7v_2$ so the first column is $\begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}$.

Do the same for $v_2'= 5v_1+ 2v_2$.